# Custom Data error in Microsoft Bot Service

Tags: android, azure, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I am facing an issue while hitting the below url of Direct Line API:

https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/Conversationid/activities

Header i am passing :
token

Bdy

```
{
"type": "message",
"from": {
"id": "user1"
},
"text": "hello"
}
```

but i am getting below error

```
{
"error": {
"code": "Missing Property",
"message": "Missing 'Activity.From' field"
}
}
```

Chatbot having custom parameters but not able to figured out how to pass the same.
Can anyone help me

I have to integrate my custom Microsoft bot with Android native.

Comment: how can we test the custom parameters direct line api through postman ?

Comment: Are you certain you are generating a `token` and `conversationId` and passing those in the API call? And, just to be clear, are you replacing the "ConversationId" text in the API with your generated `conversationId` you generated? The `conversationId` would look something like this: `CexIMjVp61KGmm05Bqds32-o`. And, the complete API would look something like this: `v3/directline/conversations/CexIMjVp61KGmm05Bqds32-o/activities`.